# video tag volume control is not working in ionic

Tags: android, html, video, ionic-framework

I am using HTML video tag in my ionic app.

```
<video id="welcomeVideo" poster="img/WelcomeVideo.png" width="100%" preload="metadata" autoplay controls muted><source src="http://myWebsite.com/videos/welcome.mp4" type="video/mp4"/></video>
```

Above code works fine in the browser, but when i run it on Android device, video starts playing as I have used autoplay attribute, but muted attribute doesn't work.

Even when I pause the video, video stops but audio plays in background. Also I am not getting volume control button in the app. But in browser it works without any giving any issue.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: put the video in a video editor, set audio volume to 0 and export the video, why waste memory with audio if you needn't it?

Comment: I need audio also. I want to make it like fb videos, with auto play and mute and on-click of the video audio starts playing

Comment: could you use jquery?

Comment: I tried with Js code "video.pause();" it stops the video but not audio :(

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#welcomeVideo').volume = 0; 

});
```